# Installing Gnome 3.12 from stable repository for OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: linux, upgrade, gnome, opensuse, opensuse-13.1

I installed (upgrading) Gnome 3.12 from a stable repository for OpenSUSE 13.1, I follow this:

```
sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/GNOME:/STABLE:/3.12/openSUSE_13.1/ GNOME
sudo zypper dup
```

When the installation finishes this warning came in the terminal:

```
There are some running programs that use files deleted by recent upgrade. You may wish to restart some of them. Run 'zypper ps' to list these programs.
```

I ran `zypper ps` and the list has a lot of processes. I reboot my computer, but now the system not start, not start Logon screen.

What can I do to solve this? What did I do wrong?

Comment: So if in boot process you use ctrl+alt+f1 and go to shell.login and type startx what error do you get?

Comment: @sayth, I don't know. :( Took so long for an answer on this site that I went back to install the system with Gnome 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the very same problem.

I did

```
zypper dist-upgrade --from "name of the gnome 3.12 repository"
```

in your case

```
zypper dist-upgrade --from GNOME
```

Now openSuSE and Gnome 3.12 is working.

Lukas